# Monte Carlo simulations by large no of trials

Tags: python, probability

Consider that following program.

```
import math
import random

def inside_unit_circle(point):
    """
    Compute distance of point from origin
    """
    distance = math.sqrt(point[0] ** 2 + point[1] ** 2)
    return distance < 1


def estimate_mystery(num_trials):
    """
    Main function
    """
    num_inside = 0

    for dumm_idx in range(num_trials):
        new_point = [2 * random.random() - 1, 2 * random.random() - 1]
        if inside_unit_circle(new_point):
            num_inside += 1

    return float(num_inside) / num_trials

print estimate_mystery(10000)
```

This program uses `random.random()` to generates a random set of points that are uniformly distributed over the square with corners at

```
(1, 1) (−1, 1)
(1,−1) (−1,−1)
```

Here, being uniformly distribution means that each point in the square has an equal chance of being generated. The method then tests whether these points lie inside a unit circle.

As one increases the number of trials, the value returned by `estimate_mystery` tends towards a specific value that has a simple expression involving a well-known constant. Enter this value as a math expression below. (Do not enter a floating point number.)

Comment: You forgot to copy the actual question from the assignment

Comment: and copy the code....

Answer (score 1):

So you need to run estimate_mystery with increasingly higher numbers of trials. As you do so, it will become clear that the value increases to the following simple expression:

[image: formula]

(`\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i\pi(k+1)}}{2k-1}`)

It should be noted, however, that this is not the only correct answer. The following would have been valid too, where `\zeta` is the Riemann zeta function:

[image: formulaalternate]

However, this does not include the well-known constant `e`.

---

I'm not sure why this is confusing. It's quite clear that the sum expression is correct, and it's written quite clearly: the code below the image is very standard LaTeX formatting for mathematical expressions. But to illustrate its correctness, here's a plot showing the convergence when taking the sum to n, and running estimate_mystery up to n as well:

[image]

---

Hrmm... maybe this wasn't what your question wanted? It should also converge to the following, where `\gamma` is a unit circle around `z=0` on the complex plane:

[image]

(`-i\oint_\gamma z^{-3}e^{\frac{z}{2}}dz`)

Comment: your expression is not clear to me. write it carefully

Comment: I've tried to add a bit of clarification, but I'm not sure how the expression could be written more carefully or clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If you try `estimate_mystery()` method with different inputs such as with, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000), you will see that the result will be 0.81,  0.781 0.7807 0.7855, accordingly.

It means, the more you increase the trial number, the result is getting closer ( converges ) to 0.7855. This number can be defined with Pi.

You can find it just by simple calculation. Pi * x = 0.7855. From this equation we can find that x ~ 0.25. Therefore, 0.7855 can be described with **Pi/4**.