# how can i Loop this program

Tags: python, loops

i need to loop this program to ask the question ten times but it doesn't seem to work

```
import os
import random
import operator
 score=0
     ops={'+':operator.add,
'-':operator.sub,
 '*':operator.mul,
 '/':operator.truediv}
 name=input('what is your name? ')
 print('hello lets answer some maths',name)
 op = random.choice(list(ops)
               )
 b=random.randint(1,10)  
 a=random.randint(1,10)
 c=int(input("What is {} {} {}? ".format(float(b), op, float(a))))
 if  a+b==c:
    print("correct.")
    score+1
else:
print('incorrect.')
score+0
```

Comment: `for _ in range(10)`

Comment: by `a+b==c` do you mean `ops[op](a, b) == c`? also how exactly do you expect your program to loop without using any loop such as `for` or `while`???

Comment: Your indentation is bad. Please fix it. What do you expect `score+1` to do? You're performing arithmetic on `score` but not saving the result anywhere. Perhaps you meant `score += 1`. But `score+0` is totally useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks pretty horrible and wont work as you have random operators but you always test for an addition.

The important part is the checking if the input was correct.

python 2/3 compatible

**Disclaimer**: This inst like a perfect algorithm. eg. 6/7 will be impossible to answer.

```
import random
import operator

try:
    input = raw_input
except:
    pass

ops={
    '+' : operator.add,
    '-' : operator.sub,
    '*' : operator.mul,
    '/' : operator.truediv
}

def question():
    b=random.randint(1,10)
    a=random.randint(1,10)
    op = random.choice(list(ops))
    raw = input("What is %s %s %s? " % (a, op, b))
    try:
        c=float(raw)
    except:
        return 0

    # calls operator functions you defined        
    if c == ops[op](a,b):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    score = 0
    for n in range(10):
        score = score + question()
    print('Your socre: %s' % score)
```

Comment: yeah i though so, when i started i couldnt write anything better than what you did^

Answer (score 1):

The following will repeat exactly your code (always expecting the numbers to be added) ten times. If you want different operators, change the ops dict, but note Yannik's comments.

```
import random
import operator
ops={'+':operator.add,
'-':operator.add,
 '*':operator.add,
 '/':operator.add}
name=input('what is your name? ')
print('hello lets answer some maths',name)
score=sum((lambda v: (v,print(['incorrect','correct'][v]))[0])(
        (lambda a,f:int(f("What is {1} {0} {2}? ".format(*a)))==ops[a[0]](*a[1:]))(
            [random.choice(list(ops))]+list(map(lambda x: random.randint(1,x),[10]*2)),input))
          for _ in range(0,10))
```

Comment: This code is waaaay to complex. Poster being a beginner makes it even more unsuitable.

Comment: It's... intentionally complex. When I read this, it sounded like the user was trying to ask for us to do a homework problem, and I sometimes give correct answers to those that would not be usable as assignment answers. In hindsight, I may have been wrong here, influenced by having just given [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28982219/599265) and seeing a large number of similar do-my-homework questions. Sorry!

Comment: @user5061: In fact, it's not merely homework - it's an assessment task for the [GCSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Certificate_of_Secondary_Education) (what used to be called the O levels). See [GCSE Computing programming tasks](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2gawvg/gcse_computing_programming_tasks_14_16_year_olds/) for further details.